# replace a declared function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a small code problem:

I want a already declared function to replace it with another one.

For example, let's say i have a js file, with the function:

```
function SayHello() {
 $(".nav").addClass('sticky animated fadeInDown');
}
```

and i want to **replace** that function with another js file and a function like that:

```
function SayHello() {
 $(".nav").addClass('fadeUp');
}
```

The code is just an example, but the point is that I can't change the original js, so i want to just replace what the function does.

Any ideas on how i could do that would be appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: Umm. You do what you did there.

Comment: Oh - i can have multiple function declarations with the same name?

Comment: As long as it is declared without `const` and is in a scope you can access.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to do this.

One is to include a second function definition later down in a script tag.

The second is to set the new function in the window object

```
window.sayHello = newFooFunction;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let MyFunction = function SayHello() {
 return $(".nav").addClass('sticky animated fadeInDown');
}
```

and if u want to replace it

```
let MyFunction = function SayHello() {
 return $(".nav").addClass('fadeUp');
}
```

have a good day